# How to use OBJECTs in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, object

In other languages such as flash to create a simple object I would just use something like;

```
Object person = new Object();
person.age = 6;
person.name = "Bob"
```

How would I do something like this in ASP.NET c#.  And can I do it all directly in my 1 aspx.cs file?

Comment: .NET languages are strongly typed, meaning the compiler will not allow you to access a property not defined in its containing type (here, object). You can still use ExpandoObject, but what you want here is simply to define a Person class and instantiate it.

Comment: btw you could do something like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Euyyy8

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Age = 6;
        person.Name = "Bob";

        Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);

    }

    public class Person{
        public int Age{get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }
}
```